# when to use AKNodeRecorder and AKClipRecorder

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

I don't have much of experience with sound processing or producing or tools that people use when dealing with sound processing, and this is the reason why I reached AudioKit. Some of the classes doesn't have a brief description about the intention of them, why are they here of when should I use each of them as opposed to other closely related classes.

My concrete question is about the difference between `AKClipRecorder` and `AKNodeRecorder`. Why do we need to separate between the two of them? When to use each one of them?

Personally I use the `AKClipRecorder` only because I have a callback function that triggered when recording is done, and for example from looking into the source code I didn't understand why the `removeTap` function is located in the `deinit` function and not in `stop` function as the regular `AKNodeRecorder`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clip recorder has a few extra timing facilities for recording with a much higher degree of accuracy.

So if you wanted to record audio, play it, then record more audio that will be layered "on top" of the first recording, you'd need to use the clip recorder to achieve the accuracy needed to synchronize the second recording with the playback of the first.

The reason that the tap remains active after a clip is recorded is that you can record multiple (even overlapping) clips at a time.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. The thing is I don't really use all those features, I just need a simple recorder with a callback function, this is why I pretty much forced to use this class.